# Magento 2 Add Quantity Dropdown and to show Textbox when Quantity selection is 10 from dropdown at Cart Page

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, quantity, dropdown-attribute

I want to add dropdown of 1 to 10 of quantity at cart page and if customer choose the 10 from quantity dropdown then the textbox appears for quantity field.

please help me.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to cart page **`.phtml`** file and add below code.

```
<div class="field qty">
   <label class="label" for="qty">
       <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span>
   </label>
   <div class="control">
       <select name="qty" id="qty" title="<?php echo __('Qty') ?>" class="cart-qty">
            <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="special-quantity" class="special-quantity" name="qty" style="display:none;">
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    require(['jquery'], function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.cart-qty').change(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == '10') {
                    $('#special-quantity').show();
                } else {
                    $('#special-quantity').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Let me know if any quries.

**`Thanks`**